# terms relation & score from solr

Tags: solr, cluster-analysis, bigdata, mahout, carrot2

I have below person and his skill data already indexed in solr

```
Candidate, Skills
-----------------
1, Java, JSP, Servlet, Spring, Hibernate 
2, Java JSP, JDBC
3, Java, JDBC, RMI
4, JDBC, SQL
5, .Net, C#
```

from above I would like build terms relationship data with each skills and how much they are related, so later this information can be used for better candidate search for any requirement & new skills can be properly associated with existing skills.

based on research what i found that i need to cluster my vector terms may be mahout or carrot2, but i am not sure how this can how this can be performed.

i believe carrot2 does in memory clustering so scaling can be issue so preferred option i am looking at mahout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mahout is the library for **distributed** and **scalable** machine learning algorithms. So if your data size is less then 500Gb and you do not expect use more then 1 machine - Carrot2 or Weka or python scikit + nltk is a right choice. Otherwise Mahout. Second point is that Mahout can work with Solr vectors "out of the box".

Comment: `Second point is that Mahout can work with Solr vectors "out of the box"` is it possible to provide more detail bcoz i am looking for that only

Comment: Solr use Lucene vector format for indexing. Mahout, "out of the box" has a util for converting Lucene index to Mahout vector 

( https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html )

So if Solr index is stored in $SOLR/index then just 


$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout lucene.vector $SOLR/index --output /tmp/tmp.vec --field body --weight tfidf

Answer (score 0):

Carrot2 is suitable for clustering of natural text (such as web pages, news articles), while your data is really a set of symbols. Therefore, Carrot2 will not help you much in this task. Mahout does have a number of clustering algorithms suitable for your data, you can also try [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/index.html) which comes with a comprehensive set of machine learning tools and a UI.